# Change inner property of an array of objects without a loop

Tags: javascript

I want to change following code, I want to insert user_uuid into each one of the object in the array but I dont want to use loop.

```
const test = [
    { n: 1, m: 2 },
    { n: 6, m: 2 },
    { n: 3, m: 4 }
];

const user_uuid = 3;
```

is there a way to change to

```
const test = [
    { n: 1, m: 2,user_uuid:3 },
    { n: 6, m: 2,user_uuid:3 },
    { n: 3, m: 4,user_uuid:3 }
];
```

Comment: Don't want to use a loop because why?

Comment: There are functions and libraries that will do this for you without you having to type the loop, but inside the functions there will be a loop

Comment: It is an array, you must loop in some way, like forEach or something like that.

Comment: Looping over the array is the most sensible way of doing it. I don't understand why you wouldn't want to use a loop.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming there isn't anything special about those objects,¹ no, there is no way to do that without *some* kind of loop.

The simple straightforward way to do it is...an actual loop:

```
for (const entry of test) {
    entry.user_uuid = 3;
}
```

Or there's `forEach`:

```
test.forEach(entry => {
    entry.user_uuid = 3;
});
```

But `forEach` is still a loop, the loop is just within `forEach`, where it calls your callback on each iteration.

Similarly you could use `map` and build new objects and a new array using property spread (ES2018+):

```
test = test.map(entry => ({...entry, user_uuid: 3}));
```

...but it's still a loop.

---

¹ The exception is if:

1. All of the objects you want to change share the same prototype, and
2. No objects you *don't* want to change have that prototype

In that situation, where the objects are special in that way, you can do it by adding the property to the prototype:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(test[0]).user_uuid = 3;
```

That doesn't literally add the property to the objects, and it won't be included if you (for instance) use `JSON.stringify` on those objects, but doing `test[1].user_uuid` will give you the value `3` in that special case.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I was just trying to use object and array destructuring.

Comment: @SugumarVenkatesan - That makes sense. No, none of the new stuff applies properties across all objects in an array like that.